# Given prime ideals $\mathfrak p_A,\mathfrak p_B$ of commutative rings $A,B$ respectively, to determine $ht(\mathfrak p_A \times \mathfrak p_B)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension

Let $A,B$ be commutative rings with unity. Let $\mathfrak p_A,\mathfrak p_B$ be prime ideals of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Is there a way to determine $ht(\mathfrak p_A \times \mathfrak p_B)$ where $\mathfrak p_A \times \mathfrak p_B$ is the product ideal in $A \times B$  in terms of $ht(\mathfrak p_A), ht(\mathfrak p_B)$ ?

Comment: Are you looking at the product ideal in the product ring $A\times B$. Notice that then, this is not a prime ideal and the minimal primes containing these are $\mathfrak{p}_A\times B$ and the other way around.

Comment: @Mohan: Yes I see that $\mathfrak p_A \times B$ and $A \times \mathfrak p_B$ are the only two minimal prime ideals over $\mathfrak p_A \times \mathfrak p_B$ ... and $ht (\mathfrak p_A \times B)=ht (\mathfrak p_A)$ right ?